# Would 10 cm of nonstandard wire be able to transmit gigabit Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, cables

I'm trying to run a Cat 5 cable through a wall.

Bad news is that it is a rented wall so no drilling.
Good news is that there is already a hole in the wall.
Bad news is that the hole is already in use for an old-school TV antenna cable and too small to fit a Cat 5 cable next to it.
Good news is that the hole isn't completely filled and can fit a thinner cable.

So here I was thinking that if I get 8 of the thinnest wires I can find at the local electronics store then it will probably fit. I know ethernet has standards that are supposed to ensure certain signal characteristics but perhaps these standards are loose enough to survive 10 cm of random skinny non-twisted copper?

Once upon a time as a kid I patched together scrap wires to transmit 10 Mbit Ethernet over 20 m away from my neighbors window to mine so I got that wealth of experience to draw from. Should this work?

Comment: Welcome! You will violate the specification but if you keep the pairs twisted, I’d give you a decent chance of success.

Comment: Try it and see (you're not likely to hurt anything, and there's nearly no risk of causing physical damage).  Congratulations, you are now a scientist.  Welcome to the neighborhood.

Comment: If you can't fit a normal size CAT5 cable, have you considered the thinnest CAT5 you can find?

Comment: Per @winny's suggestion, just take the four twisted pairs out of a piece of CAT5 cable (preserve the existing twisting) and run them individuallly along the coax. Punch them directly into connectors on either side of the wall.

Comment: The antenna is still in use?

Comment: Flat Ethernet cable is available.

Answer (score 2):

> Good news is that the hole isn't completely filled and can fit a thinner cable.

This is more of a home improvement question. The hole goes through drywall, I presume? If so, just enlarge it a tiny bit. Nobody knowing specifically to look for it will even notice, and then it's not like you did extensive damage or anything like that. Unfortunately, landlords can be predatory sometimes, but if that's the case, it won't matter whether you actually modified the property in any way at all. They'll try to get your money either way on all sorts of false claims.

Don't mess with special cables etc., I'd say. No point to it. You can always patch up the hole. When I rented, we did all sorts of modifications - custom shelving, custom paint, and then just undid it all before moving out - nobody could tell that anything was changed after we left. It's extra effort and not worth it for many people, of course. Messing with cabling for something as trivial as a cat5 drop is IMHO unnecessary as well. Use a small screwdriver or something like that to enlarge the hole and pull cat5, done.

Answer (score 2):

IF the cable inners will pass through the hole with the outer sheath removed then, depending on length,  you should / may :-) be able to maintain adequate signal quality.

For minimum impact, insert sheathless wires through the wall and use a short tail to a new connector.  You'll get some sort of impedance bump from sheath alteration and from the connector - but quite probably bearable.

BUT

The "old school TV cable" is more likely to withstand modifying.
Remove TC cable.
Insert CAT5.
Play with TV cable alternatives.
Worst case this can be a short range tv signal extender.